# Universal value for dictionary

Tags: c#, xna

I have a `Dictionary<key,dataValue>`. 
The problem is that `dataValue` can be typeof int, float, vector2, vector3, byte, short, uint or bool. 
I would like to avoid boxing so I can't make dataValue an object.

Can I create a data type (class or struct) that could store any data type in same byte array? Enum inside data type would hold type (int,float,bool...), so that we would know how to interpret the data in byte array?

EDIT:
Code can be unsafe.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct TestUnion 
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] 
    public int i;
    [FieldOffset(0)] 
    public double d;
    [FieldOffset(0)] 
    public char c;
    [FieldOffset(0)] 
    public byte b1;
}
```

Would something like this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit) and FieldOffset attributes to create equivalent functionality. I'll assume that you meant a 64-bit data structure, which would contain 8 bytes or 2 ints. If you really did mean a 64-byte data structure, you would need to define a struct with 64 bytes and 16 ints. (Probably better to use a byte[] and a int[].) You can find information here:

http://winfx.msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/dv_csref/html/163ab9b5-46f6-4d78-9025-f7bbba89b2e1.asp

For instance:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct ByteArray {
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public byte Byte1;
  [FieldOffset(1)]
  public byte Byte2;
  [FieldOffset(2)]
  public byte Byte3;
  [FieldOffset(3)]
  public byte Byte4;
  [FieldOffset(4)]
  public byte Byte5;
  [FieldOffset(5)]
  public byte Byte6;
  [FieldOffset(6)]
  public byte Byte7;
  [FieldOffset(7)]
  public byte Byte8;
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public int Int1;
  [FieldOffset(4)]
  public int Int2;
}
```

One thing to be careful of is the endian-ness of the machine if you plan to run it on non-x86 platforms that may have differing endianness. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness for an explanation.

Comment: Note that this would allow you to avoid having the memory to store each type, but it does mean that the memory of the struct is equal to the memory of the largest type it needs to store.  If even one of the inner types is rather large, the rest suffer as well (just not as much as more naive implementations).  Note you'd alsmost certainly want to add other fields also set with an offset of 0 for each of the types you want to use, int, bool, float, etc, so that you don't need to byte out all of the types, just for convenience sake.  +1 for only non-boxing solution.

Comment: @Servy I agree with you, so ZIGZAG I recommend you use boxing otherwise any other solution would have its downsides in terms of memory

Comment: Largest type for now would be Vector3 (that contains 3 floats, so max is 12 bytes). Would each type start with offest of 0 or does that depend on endianness? Platforms would be x86 and ARM (android, iOS).

Comment: @zigzag You can have each type start wherever you want, but you should start each at 0.  If you add additional fields here for `float`, `double`, etc. and have each with an offset of zero, rather than breaking them up into bytes yourself, then you don't need to bother worrying about endianness.

Comment: @Mauricio Gracia in my case, this code is going to be high frequency so tradeoff of some memory for not boxing and putting pressure on GC seems reasonable. To have optimal memory usage without boxing is probably not possible.